# Rust difference between creating variables

Tags: rust

I started learning rust and I'm unsure what is the difference between creating variables like this

```
let mut word = String::new();
```

and

```
let mut word = "";
```

and also
what is a variable which has & infront of it, thanks for your help I hope it's not a very stupid question.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different string-like types in Rust.

`String` is the type of *owned* strings. If you have a `String`, you have total ownership over it. You can modify it, append to it, empty it, and, yes, even drop it. You can pass ownership to someone else, you can let someone else borrow it, and so on. If you take a reference to a `String`, you get a `&String` (an immutable reference to a `String`). This type is fairly useless, and most style checkers will warn you about that. On the other hand, the *mutable* reference of `String`, denoted `&mut String`, can be useful since the borrower can append to the string without taking ownership of it.

`str` is a string slice. It's an *unsized* type, so it can't be used as a function argument or a structure component without being wrapped in a reference or a `Box`. Most commonly, you see it in the form `&str`, which is an immutably-borrowed string slice. Since this is a reference, it's sized and thus can be used in most conventional contexts.

`String::new` returns, as the name implies, a new owned `String`. A string literal such as `""` has type `&'static str`, i.e. a borrowed string slice with static lifetime.

You can borrow a `String` as a `&str` with [`as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str), or with the `Deref` instance for `String`. The latter will often kick in automatically if you try to call a `str` method on a `String`. On the other hand, there's no way to treat a `&str` as a `String`, since the former is borrowed and the latter implies ownership, a stronger guarantee. If you want to go the other way, you need to *copy* the data from the `&str` into a new `String`. This can be done in a couple of ways, simply by using different traits.

```
String::from(my_str)
my_str.to_owned()
```

Personally, I use `String::from` on string literals (i.e. `String::from("some constant")`) and `to_owned` on variables, but that's by no means a universal rule.

In summary, `String` is the type of owned strings, and `&str` is the type of borrowed string slices. String literals in Rust have type `&'static str`.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of understand, but also seem to have a problem I'm trying to iterate trough a vec<i32> names nums like this for x in nums.iter(), the problem is my x value is &i32 and I can't compare it to a i32 value.

Comment: Numbers like `i32` are easy because they're `Copy`, which means you can freely copy them. To go from `i32` to `&i32`, put an `&` in front of it. To go from `&i32` to `i32`, put a `*` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, also Is doing that considered a bad practice? Is it okay if I convert i32 to &i32 also is it better to make them both &i32 or i32

Comment: For `Copy` types, strip off references when you can, so go for `i32`. For types that are not `Copy`, like strings or vectors, you'll have to use `&` more often since it's not cheap to copy them.